# Dynamic URL with QuertyTables.Add VBA

Tags: vba, url, dynamic

I'm trying to download data from a weather website (weather.gov) and trying to use variables for the latitude and longitude in the URL.  If I go to the website and switch out the latitude and longitude manually, I will be directed to the correct city's weather forecast.  However, when I try to set the latitude and longitude as a variable and combine the part of the URL that doesn't change with the variables for each city, it give me a compile error, `Expected: list separator or )`.  It keeps getting stuck on this section `("&lon=-")` in the URL.  I'm not sure if there's a better way to declare the variable or add them in, but it doesn't make much sense to me why it doesn't like that middle section.  Code below.  Thanks!

P.S. The `cityLat` and `cityLong` variables would be values based on the city, but for right now I just have the actual latitude and longitude just to test it with.

```
Sub forecast_weather()
    Dim cityLon As String
    Dim cityLat As String

    cityLat = "41.8781"
    cityLong = "87.6298"

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Chicago Weather").Select

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
         "URL;http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat="&cityLat&"&lon=-
         "&cityLong&"&unit=0&lg=english&FcstType=text&TextType=2", _
         Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
         .Name = "q?s=usdCAd=x_1"
         .FieldNames = True
         .RowNumbers = False
         .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
         .PreserveFormatting = True
         .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
         .BackgroundQuery = True
         .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
         .SavePassword = False
         .SaveData = True
         .AdjustColumnWidth = True
         .RefreshPeriod = 0
         .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
         .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
         .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
         .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
         .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
         .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
         .WebDisableRedirections = False
         .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need spaces around the `&`

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
   "URL;http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=" & cityLat & _
    "&lon=" & cityLong & "&unit=0&lg=english&FcstType=text&TextType=2", _
        Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
```

Comment: *facepalm* Thanks so much!  So easy and it works great!

Answer (score 0):

this gets Chicago weather

```
Sub forecast_weather()
    Dim cityLon As String
    Dim cityLat As String

    cityLat = "41.8781"
    cityLong = "-87.6298"

    With Worksheets("sheet1").QueryTables.Add( _
            Connection:="URL;http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?" _
            & "lat=" & cityLat _
            & "&lon=" & cityLong _
            & "&unit=0&lg=english&FcstType=text&TextType=2", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "q?s=usdCAd=x_1"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```